# Why is my code not working on more than one thread?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I have been trying to multi-thread my code, it still works, but only uses 15% of my cpu (i have 8 threads, so thats 1 thread).

I have tried many scripts to multi-thread from stack overflow and youtube, but none worked.

```
import threading

n=2

def crazy():
    global n
    while True:
        n = n*2
        print(n)

threads = []
for i in range(4):
    t = threading.Thread(target=crazy)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
```

The ouput is as expected, but only running on one thread.

Comment: I think you may want to use multiprocessing instead of threading. My understanding is that that the threading module doesn't parallelize the code it just switches between threads and executes one at a time.

Comment: "Threads" in Python are not real threads. For CPU bound tasks use multiprocessing: https://www.ploggingdev.com/2017/01/multiprocessing-and-multithreading-in-python-3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in fact using threads (all 4 of them). You can test by implementing a pause in your code:

```
import threading
import time

n = 2

def crazy():
    global n
    while True:
        n = n*2
        print(n)
        time.sleep(1) # pause

threads = []
for i in range(4):
    t = threading.Thread(target=crazy)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
```

Where at first it prints:

```
4
8
16
32
```

Then a second later prints

```
64
128
256
512
```

The fact that it prints in groups of 4 is evidence that 4 threads are running, and each is encountering a pause in execution. If you are trying to maximize CPU usage, perhaps multiprocessing is more along the lines of what you are looking for? `threading` simply imitates multiple things happening at once, while `multiprocessing` actually makes multiple things happen at once. Note that multiprocessing is a bit trickier, as you have to be clever to avoid deadlock.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot, wasnt aware that multiprocessing even existed. Thats probably what im trying to do.

Comment: @JameEnder OK! Just a heads up, this task is a very poor one to utilize `multiprocessing` (or even `threading` really) on due to its linear nature (each computation depends on the previous one). To truly utilize multiprocessing, each process should be able to run independently of the other computations happening simultaneously. I find myself filling a `queue.Queue()` and passing this to my threads/processes to unload!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

n = 2


def crazy(_):
    global n
    while True:
        n = n * 2
        print(n)

threads = []
pool = Pool(8)
pool.map(crazy, range(8))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: Still hovering at around 15% cpu usage, with some 20% usage spikes.

Answer (score 0):

This is running multiple python threads, however, python threads are at the application level and not the kernel. These application threads take turns running on the same core, but they are indeed context switching. For example take the output of this code. It switches between threads to print the numbers:

```
import threading

n=0
def crazy(i):
    global n
    for i in range(4):
        n = n + 1
        print(f"Thread {i}: {n}")

threads = []
for i in range(4):
    t = threading.Thread(target=crazy, args=(i,))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
```

Outputs:

```
Thread 0: 1
Thread 1: 2
Thread 2: 3
Thread 3: 4
Thread 0: 5
Thread 1: 6
Thread 2: 7
Thread 3: 8
Thread 0: 9
Thread 1: 10
Thread 2: 11
Thread 3: 12
Thread 0: 13
Thread 1: 14
Thread 2: 15
Thread 3: 16
```

Answer (score 0):

No CPU speed up can be connected with Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) you  can read about it here https://realpython.com/python-gil/ and google about GIL